# Accessing and using the files in the app sandbox

Tags: ios, sandbox

I have an iOS application in which I download some files from a remote server and store them in the app sandbox directory, Documents. I am sure the files are saved in the sandbox properly because when I run the following piece of code:

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString* documentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSError* error;
NSLog(@"%@",[fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentPath error:&error]);
```

I get the following output:

```
2014-07-09 17:39:07.768 Sample[13413:60b] (
    "test.json",
    "test.png"
)
```

However, I can not access these files in the Documents directory. I try to get the contents of test.json with the following code:

```
NSString* testJsonDir = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"json"];
NSString* testJson = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:testJsonDir encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

This returns testJsonDir as nil and gives an error with code 258. Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: the `bundle` and a `Documents` folder are two different things. a file can be in the `bundle`, that you need to use `NSBundle` to get the path for it; or the file can be in the `Documents` folder, you need to use the `NSFileManager` to get the path for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[NSBundle mainBundle]` refers to the .app bundle, not the Documents directory. To access test.json, use this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *documentsUrl = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask][0];
NSString *testJson = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[documentsUrl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.json"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

I'm using `-URLsForDirectory:inDomains:` instead of `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()` because former is a preferred way.

Answer (score 1):

`[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:]` will locate files within the app bundle, not the documents folder.

You want:

```
NSString *testJsonDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *testJsonFile = [testJsonDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.json"];
NSString *testJson = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:testJsonFile
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                  error:&error];
```